# JTextArea Getting Cut Off in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a program that takes in some equations from the user. I want each constant to be entered in a `JTextField`, with each separated by a `JTextArea` (saying +x0, +x1, etc.). However, I can't quite get the formatting to work, and I'm not sure why. Here's the relevant code:

```
JTextField[][] dataTextFields = new JTextField[a+1][b+1];
JTextArea[][] dataLabels = new JTextArea[a][b+1]; 

for (int i = 0; i < a+1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < b+1; j++)
    {
        dataTextFields[i][j] = new JTextField(10);
        dataTextFields[i][j].setLocation(5+70*i, 10+30*j);
        dataTextFields[i][j].setSize(40,35);
        dataEntryPanel.add(dataTextFields[i][j]);

        if (i < a)
        {
            String build = "x" + Integer.toString(i) + "+";
            dataLabels[i][j] = new JTextArea(build);
            dataLabels[i][j].setBackground(dataEntryPanel.getBackground());
            dataLabels[i][j].setBounds(45+70*i,20+30*j,29,30);
            dataEntryPanel.add(dataLabels[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

This creates `JTextFields` with `JTextAreas` 0f "+xi" in between them. However, when I run the applet, it looks like this:

[image]

I can click on the labels and bring them to the foreground, it seems, resulting in this:

[image]

I'd like for the labels to be visible without any effort from the user, obviously. Does JTextArea have some attribute that can be changed to bring this to the foreground? I'd really prefer not to add any more UI elements (panels, containers, etc). Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that what is happening is that you've basically wrote your own layout manager by specifying exact bounds for each component.  I doubt the Swing painting/rendering/layout code takes kindly to that since it's trying to delegate that to whatever layout manager is already present on the component.  Have you tried using something like GridLayout or GridBagLayout to see if that solves your problem?  Or maybe a series of FlowLayouts inside of a GridBag so that each flow renders directly under the previous, giving you rows of components like you have in your screenshot.

Comment: which layout you are using ? please add the relevant code for JLabel too

Comment: @Sage oh, I misspoke. I actually ended up using JTextArea instead of JLabel; I couldn't get JLabels to show up at all.

Comment: @mattforsythe Yeah, I made the layout null so I could manipulate everything how I wanted. I may have to try GridBagLayout, thanks

Comment: I also agree this looks like a classic layout issue. Sometimes a simple call to revalidate() or repaint() can correct this kind of issue though using a non-null layout is still the safest.

Comment: Let me know if this solves your issue, and I can write up a more detailed answer to that effect.  You may want to include the fact that you've set the layout to null, and that you are using JTextArea instead of JLabel in the question, so that others who come across it will know what is going on.

Comment: The solution actually was that there was a blank panel in the way. Originally, the JFrame shows several panels, allowing the user to enter some parameters for the problem. Then, upon clicking the Proceed button, all previous panels are whisked away with setVisible(false) and the dataEntryPanel is set to visible. But, I just forgot to set one of the original panels to false. Anyway, I'd still like to know how to even get it going; I tried to set up a GridBagLayout but didn't even know where to begin.

Comment: @CoconutJones - Added an answer to show example of a `GridBagLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

I would layout the container using `GridBagLayout`.  `GridBagLayout` works a lot like HTML tables, where you have different cells, which grow in height and width to try and accommodate the content most effectively.  For your particular layout, something like this would work:

```
public class SwingTest extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run () {
                new SwingTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    public SwingTest () {
        super("Swing Test");
        
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        
        contentPane.add(createJTextField(), gbc.clone());
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("x0+"), gbc.clone());
        contentPane.add(createJTextField(), gbc.clone());
        
        // go to next line
        gbc.gridy++;
        
        contentPane.add(createJTextField(), gbc.clone());
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("x0+"), gbc.clone());
        contentPane.add(createJTextField(), gbc.clone());
        
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    
    private JTextField createJTextField () {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(4);
        textField.setMinimumSize(textField.getPreferredSize());
        return textField;
    }
}
```

GridBagLayout is the most complicated (but flexible) of the layouts, and requires many parameters to configure.  There are simpler ones, like FlowLayout, BorderLayout, GridLayout, etc, that can be used in conjunction with one another to achieve complex layouts, as well.

In the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), there is a very good section on [Laying Out Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).  If you plan on spending any significant amount of time on building Swing GUI's, it may be worth the read.

Note, that there is one strange caveat with `GridBagLayout`: if you are going to use a `JTextField` in a `GridBagLayout`, there is one silly issue (described [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4247013)) that causes them to render at their minimum sizes if they can't be rendered at their preferred sizes (which causes them to show up as tiny slits).  To overcome this, I specify the number of columns on my `JTextField` constructor so that the minimum is something reasonable, and then set the minimum size to the preferred size.